# Gmail gadget to the right

Tags: html, xml, gmail, gmail-contextual-gadgets

Is it possible to set the position for my gadget to the right, when I'm on a mail overview.
Something similar to Rapportive gadget.
I tried using canvas, default view ... ate the whole Google doc ...

EDIT : My code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<Module>
  <ModulePrefs height="100" title="Navigation">
    <Require feature="views" />
  </ModulePrefs>
  <Content type="html" view="home">
    <![CDATA[
    <div style="color: #4386d4;">My Home view</div>
    <div>features ...</div><br><br>
    ]]>
  </Content>
  <Content type="html" view="canvas">
    <![CDATA[
    <div>canvas view</div> 
    ]]>
  </Content>
  <Content type="html" view="DEFAULT">
    <![CDATA[
    <div>Default view</div>
    ]]>
  </Content>
</Module>
```

Comment: Please be more specific. Have you tried this yet yourself? Are you just curious if it's possible? What code of yours is related to this problem?

Comment: Yes i already have a html script which is doing what i want. i would like to know how to do it.

Comment: If we are to help you, you need to show us the code you have already.

Comment: I linked the code in my first post.